# Is there a way to export Power BI tables into excel?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, daxstudio

I am trying to create a solutions process and the end-users are comfortable in Excel. Is there a way to export the tables in power bi into excel for use? I have DAX add-in if there is a way to do so with that.

I have everything able to process as needed in Power BI, and was thinking if a connection could be created to the table then it may be able to bypass the row limit and data limit for excel??

Like can each table be loaded as a connection in power query? That would definitely be helpful

Please help

Comment: [You can use PowerQuery directly from Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-data-from-external-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a). You can say "import 1000 rows from SQL, sorted by dates" Also check out Seymour's link to Analyze in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

The feature you are seeking is [Analyze in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-analyze-in-excel).

This built-in solution allows you to connect an Excel to the same data source as Power BI. Then, you can create your visualization in Excel.

Comment: Will this retain the same amount of rows as well? (I have 5M rows)

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What information do you need exactly?

Comment: I want to export the processed table and calculations back to Excel. I am working in power bi as the limits are much larger than that of excel, but the individuals in my organization are not familiar with how to work in power bi, so I have to figure out some way to have a power query connection back into Excel if possible for the table